# A continuous nowhere differentiable function having additive property.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm not sure whether this is duplicated or not.

What I'd like to find is an example of a continuous nowhere complex differentiable function satisfying $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)+f(z_2)$ for all $z_1, z_2$ in $ \mathbb{C}$.

I already know Weierstass function is an example of real valued continuous but nowhere differentiable function.

But is there such a complex valued function satisfying above conditions?

Any reference or direct explanation would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Obvious example $f(z)=\bar{z}$

Comment: @user10354138 ....How I couldn't think about that.... I feel so embarassed.

Comment: Me, too.  Any $\mathbb R$-linear $f$ will do the trick (such as $\Im z$ and $\Re(z)$ etc) but most of them are not complex-differentiable. I red-facedly consider this a trick question.

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that every continuous additive function on $\Bbb R$ is linear. In particular, there are $c_1,c_2$ such that $f(t)=c_1t$ and $f(it)=c_2t$. Then $f(x+iy)=c_1x+c_2y$